# Offloading SQL Report Server processing to a dedicated server - is it worth it?

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services

Not sure if this is a SO or a ServerFault question, so please feel free to move if it's not in the right place:

I have a client with a large database containing a table with around 30-35 million rows running on a SQL2008R2 server (the server is pretty high spec, 16 cores, 92 gig ram, RAID etc). There are other tables this table may join on, but it is the main driver of a several reports.

Their SSRS instance/database and query source database are both running on the same box/sql instance

They regularly run ad-hoc reports from this database (which have undergone extensive optimisation), many of which may end up touching a lot of the data in the table. After looking at the report server stats it appears that the data fetch doesn't actually take that long, but a lot of data is returned and report processing takes a fair while: it can take up to 20-30 minutes to process some of the larger reports, which can have tens of thousands of pages (the data fetch in these cases is less than 10 seconds).

(**Note:** I realise that there is never really a need to run 25,000 pages off but the client insists and won't listen to reason...something about Excel spreadsheets ****FACEPALM!****)

At the moment they are concerned about a couple of performance issues that crop up sporadically and the culprit may be the ad-hoc reporting.

We are looking at offloading the report processing anyway, so thought that this would be an ideal opportunity - but before doing so I'm wondering how much relief this will give the SQL server.

If I move the SSRS app and database onto another SQL host and remotely query the data (network conditions should be ideal as this is datacentre based), will I see any performance gains?

This is mainly based on guesswork at this stage but I see the following being the factors that could affect performance:

- I/O for moving a shedload of rows from the query source to RS temp DB
- CPU load when the report server is crunching all the data

In moving to another host I see these factors being reduced for the SQL server. The new server will be solely responsible for report processing (and should also be high spec), so hopefully there will be no contention when processing reports.

Do I sound like I am on the right track in my assumptions? Is there anything else that I may have missed which could adversely affect performance or improve performance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at transactional replication to send data from the main server to a database on the reporting server.  Querying the tables directly over the network will only slow things down even more.

Comment: We will be replicating the servers but not for this purpose. I suggested that querying over the network would possibly pose a performance penalty but some others disagreed.

Comment: I would highly recommend against doing it over the network since that will only be detrimental to both the main server's OLTP workload, and the report consumers will complain of further slowness.

Comment: I'll accept that, I'll probably update my answer with our findings after the fact, but thanks for the information